# The value of the vector $\vec{A}$ is given as $15$cm, and the focal lenght is $12$cm. What is the size of resulting image?

Tags: physics

[image]

The value of the vector ﻿﻿$\vec{A}$ is given as $15$cm, and the focal lenght is $12$cm. Assume that $﻿﻿M$=﻿﻿ Center, ﻿﻿$F$=﻿﻿ Focal point of this concave mirror. What is the size of resulting image?

I've tried to apply the Mirror Formula $\frac{1}{f} = \frac{1}{d_0} = \frac{1}{d_i}$. However, there should be anything I'm missing. Can you correct me?

Comment: Can anyone take a look at the question? It's not that hard to share your thinkings/tips/hints. You don't need to be a physicist or something. Think as an mathematician. I'm still thinking on it.

Comment: Does anyone have any idea? am training for physics olympiads, need your professional helps too much.

Comment: Is this mirror parabolic?

Comment: @amd that's concave mirror.

Comment: Yes, I can see that it’s concave, but what is its shape?

Comment: @amd what do you actually mean by shape?

Comment: What I’ve already asked: is the mirror’s surface a parabola, circle, or something else?

Comment: @amd nearly parabola.